# Is there any way to use a java profiler for spring boot application that is deployed in azure kubernetes service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-aks, jprofiler, openjdk-11

We are trying to monitor a spring boot application that is deployed in the azure kubernetes cluster but the java profile can't monitor it since the JVM is not exposed. Also, I checked the running services in the pod/container but I did not see any JVM process that is listening to a port.

Please check the gradle steps we do when building the docker image:

```
docker {
    springBootApplication {
        baseImage = 'openjdk:11-jdk-slim'
        ports = [8080]
        images= ["docker_image"]
        jvmArgs = ['-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom']
    }
}
```